# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Identity 2FA using SMS, Not Authenticated after TwoFactorSignInAsync() with multiple schemas

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-authentication

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 solution and I copied the functionality for SMS 2FA from  version 1.1. All good, I receive the sms with code I validate the code and `_signInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync` result.Succeeded = true.

However, I have 2 schemas defined in my Startup. Normal users and Admin users. Admin users have 2FA enabled, normal users not.

```
  services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn";                  
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;


            });


 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = 
 CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie("User", options =>
                   {
                       options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn";
                       options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                   })
                   .AddCookie("Admin", options =>
                   {
                       options.LoginPath = "/Admin/Login";
                       options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Admin/AccessDenied";
                   });
```

And then on the AdminController I have this: `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Admin")]`

The flow goes like this:

- redirect to correct login page
- username + password login is success
- after success I am redirected to SMS code validation
- validation is success
- redirect to Index page of the Admin controller, will bring me back to login page instead as unauthenticated.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?